# How should I think about salaries in New Zealand relative to the United States?

Tags: united-states, foreign-currency, new-zealand

Let's imagine I live in the United States and make about 100,000 USD.

If I move to New Zealand for a few years, I expect to make about the same, but denominated in New Zealand dollars. That is, make 100,000 NZD.

However, when we take exchange ratio into consideration between the two currencies (currently at 1 NZD = 0.66 USD), my salary ends up being 66,000 USD, effectively leaving me with a 33% pay cut.

Assuming living expenses and taxes are the same in their respective currencies, am I correct to assume that moving to New Zealand from the United States is a bad deal? The only way I end up even is if the New Zealand dollar ever catches up to the United States dollar, which given its history, is very unlikely to happen.

Am I missing something? Or this is pretty much it?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but I believe the answer covers your question neatly. Effectively, to your question "Am I missing something?" the answer is, "Yes - you are missing something by assuming that the cost of living is the same in both countries - and more specifically, that it is the same in both cities".

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon I did research on cost of living for Auckland, NZ, and it is about the same, cheaper if you were paid in USD obviously.

Comment: The currency you are paid is irrelevant to cost of living which makes me think you are getting confused by exchange rates and raw numbers and not making a valid comparison.  For instance you say that cost of living is the same in NZ as where you live now.  This would mean that taking a 35% pay cut would significantly impact your standard of living or ability to save.  However you then say it's cheaper if you are paid in USD which makes no sense and makes me think that you are saying the cost of living is the same if it's USD 15k  in the US and NZD 15k in New Zealand which is not correct.

Comment: Your last example is exactly what I'm saying, and yes, it is correct.

Comment: @Fattie I literally explicitly said "...but denominated in New Zealand dollars", and followed up with the 100,000 NZD example to make it crystal clear. I don't know what else I could've done to make it not "incredibly confusing".

Comment: The median house in Auckland costs over NZ$700k, isn't insulated, and leaks. If you think you're going to have any kind of quality of life here on NZ$100k, think again.

Answer (score 2):

It's not moving to New Zealand that's a bad idea, it's taking a pay cut. Move for a job paying NZD150K and there's no problem. You'd have exactly the same issue if you were taking a job in the US paying USD67K. It may be more difficult to find a job in New Zealand paying an amount that you would consider acceptable, but that's a different issue.

Comment: This spills more into the economics side of things, but is it unreasonable for me to expect a 150,000 NZD salary, simply due to the fact that New Zealand's economy (on a GDP per capita basis), is behind the United States?

Comment: Why is taking a pay cut to live in a more desirable location a bad idea?

Answer (score 0):

Earning 100k in USD and moving to New Zealand and to make 100k NZD would be a pay cut.

If making 66k in the US equates to 100k NZD in New Zealand and the cost of living and taxes is the same in each country then you would have the same financial quality of life in either country.

If the New Zealand dollar ever caught  up to the United States dollar, an equivalent NZD salary (66k US vs 100k NZD) would be worth a  51% bump in buying power.

Comment: I understand that the quality of life would be the same, but I'm more concerned in the long-term, specifically, the value of the money that I can stash away. If I stay in the U.S and save 50,000 USD over ten years, I'd be waaaay ahead after the ten years compared to the other me who moved to New Zealand and managed to put away 50,000 NZD a year; assuming exchange rates stay about the same. Correct?

Comment: If there are different currency valuations and/or different taxation/cost of living issues, you must put them on the same scale to make valid comparisons.   You are not doing that so therefore, your comparisons are apples to oranges.

Comment: I did the research, and already put taxation and cost of living on the scale. That's where the $50,000 come from.